# vscode devcontainer with ssh agent forwarding

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my dockerfile I am using the mount ssh funtion documented [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run---mounttypessh). That works great as long as I build using the command `$ docker buildx build --ssh default=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK .` (as documented).

Now my problem is that I want to use that in the vs code dev container. I can get it to work using the line:

```
"initializeCommand": "docker buildx build --ssh default=${SSH_AUTH_SOCK} --target dev .",
```

but that way the build section (see below) usually containing the target gets overwritten/ not used and I have to also to put the target in the command above.

```
"build": {
        "context": "..",
        "dockerfile": "../Dockerfile",
        "target": "dev",

    },
```

I feel like there should be an easier/ nicer way to do that.
I found this ticket that (I think) talks about the exact same topic and claims to have fixed it. However I can't get it to work (maybe I don't get what exact settings are used to set the things I need).

So a clear explanation of what I need to tweak to end up with a nicer `devcontainer.json` would be welcome.